# How to format dates with one column - day of week and another column - month using R

Tags: date, formatting

I have this data set in excel format (2 different columns) which looks like this:

```
month   day_of_week
may     mon
may     mon
```

How do I insert the year and format it as dd-mm-yyyy using R?

Comment: 2 different columns - month, day of the week

Comment: Your information in Excel is insufficient to convert to an absolute date because a given month can have multiple days all on Monday.  Best thing would be to just export year-month-day information from Excel.